# Visio 2013 - Getting C# to work as Macros?

Tags: c#, vba, sdk, visual-studio-2013, visio

I am trying to open a Visio 2013 document and iterate over the flow chart objects, in sequential order, using the Visio 2013 SDK ([Visio 2013 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=36825)), after which custom code will be implemented to write values from the flowchart objects to a text file. The goal is to be able to do all of this using C# rather than built-in VBA macros within Visio. Is this possible, and if so are there any entry point code samples available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you can do in VBA, you can do in C# as well (by adopting syntax of course). Means, Visio object model is equally accessible from VBA and C#. As for the code sample, it's not quite clear what you mean by "iterating in sequential order". For example, what would you do if shapes on a diagram form a cycle? It has no begin and no end.. Or a tree?

Although, you can rather easily enumerate all shapes and all connections separately:

```
using System;
using Visio = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var app = new Visio.Application();
            var doc = app.Documents.Open(args[0]);

            var page = doc.Pages[1];

            foreach (Visio.Shape shp in page.Shapes)
                Console.WriteLine("shape #{0}: text: '{1}'", shp.ID, shp.Text);

            foreach (Visio.Connect conn in page.Connects)
                Console.WriteLine("connector: #{0} -> #{1}", conn.FromSheet.ID, conn.ToSheet.ID);

            app.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at these threads:

[C# code to read visio shape's connectivity with other shapes in a flow chart](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/60ebf2ed-5468-4240-95e7-6c8018a45018/c-code-to-read-visio-shapes-connectivity-with-other-shapes-in-a-flow-chart?forum=visiogeneral)

[Traverse through every possible path in a Visio Flow-Chart with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20290308/traverse-through-every-possible-path-in-a-visio-flow-chart-with-c-sharp)

Note that to simply write values from shapes to a text file, you can use "Shape Reports" button on "Review" tab. See more about "Shape Reports" in Visio:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lm1ZrkPpI1U

Comment: Thank you, the three lines I needed were the ones that open the document, I realized once you posted that why my code wasn't working it was passing the program a page that was causing me such a headache.